# (nginx/selinux) Permission denied error for sessions but files are created

Tags: php, linux, session, nginx, selinux

I have centos 7 running nginx/php-fpm with selinux enabled.

**I know there is a lot of similar questions on internet but mine is a little different.** Files are being created after setting selinux by nginx but it still says it can't read it...

tail /var/log/nginx/error.log

> 2015/10/07 16:18:25 [error] 17860#0: *79 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP
>   message: PHP Warning:  session_start():
>   open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_sk456vdemnp391spiv3i622i96, O_RDWR)
>   failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/web/api/functions.php on line
>   9

ls -la /var/lib/php/session/

> total 12 drwxrwx---+ 2 nginx nginx 82 Oct  7 16:18 . drwxr-xr-x. 3
>   root  root  20 Oct  5 15:58 ..
>   -rw-------+ 1 nginx nginx  0 Oct  7 16:15 sess_52psgccceh91vokbau4pq08946
>   -rw-------+ 1 nginx nginx  0 Oct  7 16:18 sess_sk456vdemnp391spiv3i622i96

*User of php-fpm and nginx are "nginx"
*selinux policy is changed for allowing access to session folder

Do you know which log I should check to find out what is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: The audit log from selinux is located usually in /var/log/audit.log or /var/log/audit/audit.log, if the audit daemon is not running check /var/log/avc.log

Comment: @qwattash Hi, I found the following.
type=AVC msg=audit(1444368090.415:896): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=12615 comm="php-fpm" path="/var/lib/php/session/sess_9r9np7hcsbpfcr2cg4v3b05l86" dev="dm-0" ino=68184251 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem!

My /var/lib/php/session was system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 instead of system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0. This made nginx unable to edit stuff (only create).

To fix the problem:
1- reset the policy of folder:

> restorecon -v "/var/lib/php/session"

2- then set the good one

> semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/lib/php/session

You don't even have to reload/restart nginx :P

Comment: The proper target string would be "/var/lib/php/session(/.*)?" to include everything under the session directory. Run "restorecon -R /var/lib/php/session" to apply the new policy to the session directory afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue.
In my case, the solution was to change the owner of the directory to nginx

```
chown nginx /var/lib/php/session
```